# Calculating heat loss over a maple syrup pan evaporator

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I am working on a final project for my thermo-fluids design course, and I am designing a maple syrup steam evaporator. The sap enters the evaporator through a 1.2 meter wide channel at ambient temperature, and then the steam heats it from below. The sap takes about 4.6 meters to reach saturation temperature as it flows through the pan, based on the this graph I made:

[image] .

What I want to calculate is the heat loss to the air at the water (sap) surface for this sensible heat transfer region (before the sap starts to boil). What is the best way to do this? I have the sap flowing at 0.04 meters/sec, the sap depth in the pan is 0.0254 meters. I would like to assume that the air above the sap is dry at 25 degrees C and atmospheric pressure.

Also would there be much heat loss at the surface when the sap is boiling? Or would all the heat go to evaporation at that point?

Comment: if you know the steam flow rate you can take the difference in heating versus the amount the syrup heats up.